# Insert ASTNode inside MethodDeclaration

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

I have a JDT AST `MethodDeclaration` difined like this:

```
MethodDeclaration md = ast.newMethodDeclaration();
SimpleName sn = ast.newSimpleName("myMethod");
md.setName(sn);
```

Then I created an `ASTNode` based on a `String` that contains some Java code, like this:

```
String body = "int a = 1;\n int b = 2;\n return (a + b);";

ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
parser.setSource(body.toCharArray());
parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);

ASTNode result = parser.createAST(null);
```

Now I'm trying to insert the `ASTNode` into the `MethodDeclaration` object as the body of the method so at the end it should look likt this:

```
void myMethod(){
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    return (a + b);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AST that is created by using the `ASTParser` like that is a *different* one than the one that you are operating on. Therefore, you have to convert it, using the [`org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode#copySubtree` method](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTNode.html#copySubtree-org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST-org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode-). After the conversion, you can set it as the `Body` of your `MethodDeclaration`.

Note that the `MethodDeclaration` will still have to be added to a `TypeDeclaration`, but maybe this is part of the code that you didn't show. Here is an MCVE showing the approach:

```
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.Block;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodDeclaration;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.TypeDeclaration;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.Document;
import org.eclipse.text.edits.TextEdit;

public class JDTTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        // Set the stage by creating an empty compilation unit and its AST
        ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
        parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
        parser.setSource("".toCharArray());
        CompilationUnit compilationUnit =
            (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
        compilationUnit.recordModifications();
        AST ast = compilationUnit.getAST();

        // Create the AST node with the method body. Note that this AST
        // node will belong to a diferent AST!
        ASTNode astNodeWithMethodBody = createAstNodeWithMethodBody();        

        // Create the MethodDeclaration
        MethodDeclaration methodDeclaration = ast.newMethodDeclaration();
        methodDeclaration.setName(ast.newSimpleName("myMethod"));

        // Convert the AST node with the method body to belong to
        // the desired AST, and set it as the method body
        ASTNode convertedAstNodeWithMethodBody = 
            ASTNode.copySubtree(ast, astNodeWithMethodBody);
        Block block = (Block)convertedAstNodeWithMethodBody;
        methodDeclaration.setBody(block);

        // (If necessary: Create a class declaration that will contain the 
        // newly generated method) 
        TypeDeclaration typeDeclaration = ast.newTypeDeclaration();
        typeDeclaration.setName(ast.newSimpleName("Example"));
        typeDeclaration.bodyDeclarations().add(methodDeclaration);
        compilationUnit.types().add(typeDeclaration);

        // Print the resulting document
        Document document = new Document();
        TextEdit edits = compilationUnit.rewrite(document, null);
        edits.apply(document);
        System.out.println(document.get());
    }

    private static ASTNode createAstNodeWithMethodBody()
    {
        String body = "int a = 1;\n int b = 2;\n return (a + b);";
        ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
        parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_STATEMENTS);
        parser.setSource(body.toCharArray());
        ASTNode result = parser.createAST(null);
        return result;
    }

}
```

The output is, as expected

```
class Example {
    void myMethod() {
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        return (a + b);
    }
}
```